# table sorter not working for date format with time zone

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

my html table column has a date formatted in ( MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy ) which looks like  ( Jan 25 04:31:59 IST 2020 ) . once we add timezone sorting is not working as expected . it's sorting by alphabetical order after adding timezone . 
It works well we remove timezone .

```
  $("#mediaTable").tablesorter({headers: {
     4 : {sorter: false},
     1 : {sorter: "shortDate",dateFormat:'MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy'}},
  });
```

I have tried below combinations

1 : {sorter: true ,dateFormat:'MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy'}

1 : {sorter: "longDate" ,dateFormat:'MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy'}

1 : {sorter: "usLongDate" ,dateFormat:'MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy'}

Comment: answered the question in https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/1728

Answer (score 1):

Answer available in github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/1728